# Best way to convert a huge-size mongodb to another doc format?

Tags: mongodb, database

There is a huge-size mongo db which stores over one billion documents. These documents are now in old format, I need to convert each document to a new format. What's the best way to do such a conversion?

Comment: What do you mean by "old format"?

Comment: old format ? what do you mean? is it about document or about mongodb version ?

Comment: @myildirim about document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a `version` field to your docs. If not present, assume version=1.
Then you have two possibillities:

- Convert documents "on-the-fly": client reads doc, checks version, transforms and saves back in new version. You only transform documents which are really accessed.
- Go offline, convert all documents, wait a few hours or days, go online with transformed documents.

The advantage of "schema-less" database is being able to change your schema "on-the-fly". I'd prefer first option.

Of course you can combine both options: a niced background job converts documents but clients are able to deal with old-version and new-version docs.

If you have many indexes and queries affected by your schema change, it could be difficult. Good luck!